# Findbugs Maven plugin ignores threshold

Tags: java, maven, findbugs, pom.xml

I'm using the following in my project's pom.xml file. Running a `findbugs:check` goal still fails on all errors, even when no High priority errors are present. What am I doing wrong?

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.4.0</version>
<executions>
  <execution>
    <id>failing-on-high</id>
    <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>check</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
      <threshold>High</threshold>
      <onlyAnalyze>com.example.-</onlyAnalyze>
    </configuration>
  </execution>
</executions>
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [documentation](http://mojo.codehaus.org/findbugs-maven-plugin/check-mojo.html) and trying it out on a sample codebase, it looks like `findbugs:check` goal

> Fail the build if there were ***any*** FindBugs violations in the source
>   code.

This does not seem to depend on the value of [threshold](http://mojo.codehaus.org/findbugs-maven-plugin/check-mojo.html#threshold).

Also look at [this blog entry](http://kohsuke.org/2011/08/23/my-epic-battle-with-findbugs-maven-plugin-and-how-i-utterly-lost/) which seems to describe a related problem.